# Leaky Bucket problem

Tags: networking

I have been trying to solve the following numerical problem........Any help is appreciated in making the concept clear.

"A given source request admission to a QoS network requesting avg throughput of 
2 Mbits/sec and burst capacity of 2 Mbits. The source
then transmitt data at 50 Mbits/sec for a duration of 1 millisecond. Right after 
that the source scales down the throughput to 1.8 Mbits/sec.
Plot the size of the data in the buffer reserved for this flow as a function of 
time side by side with the throughput described above. How much
data loss will this source experience? What is the burst capacity this source 
should use to ensure no data loss with throughput function show
above?"

Thank-you

Comment: My Analysis: Initially bucket o/p rate is 2 Mbits/sec and holding capacity is 2 Mbits. Client sent the data of 50/1000 Mbits for one millisec. Hence, after 1 millisecond 48/1000 Mbits of data is remaining which is present in bucket and no overflow as bucket can hold 2 Mbits of data. Now client scales down the incoming data to bucket to 1.8 Mbits/second which is less than the o/p rate of data hence there will never be data loss as 1.8 Mbits + 48/1000 < 2 Mbits.

Comment: Please correct me where i'm going wrong

Answer (score 0):

Assume

- the client is the only source of traffic.
- the buffer empties at the rate of 2 Mbits/Sec
- at T = 0, buffer is at 100% of 2Mbits (2^20 bits or about 10^6)

At T = 1 mS, 10^-3 seconds have elapsed, so 2*10^3 bytes have been cleared from the buffer. However, in that time, the client has spat out (50*10^6) bytes/sec for the 1 mS duration, or a total of 50*10^3 bytes.

As the available memory is only 2*10^3 bytes, the first 2*10^3 bytes will read correctly "off the wire", the rest (48*10^3 bytes) will be lost, or cause a fatal buffer overflow.

Somewhere, there needs to be AT LEAST another 48*10^3 bytes of memory if data loss is to be avoided. In relation to this data burst, the rest of the problem statement is meaningless, because the question appears to be asking  about the buffering required to support the given burst, and this is the peak data rate over the given graph.

I'm not sure what the answer you are seeking is, but I hope this description of the network mechanics is helpful.